# Set switchStyle - get error resource not found - why?

Tags: android, xml, widget, styles, attr

I ran into a strange Problem:
I am creating a style for an app and I set:

```
<item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/CustomSpinnerAppearance</item>  
<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/CustomTextViewAppearance</item>
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/CustomButton</item>
```

Now I wanted to set:

```
<item name="android:switchStyle">@style/CustomSwitch</item>
```

And I get this error.

> No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:switchStyle'.

I have checked in API-Lvl 14 and 15 (ICS) source the **attrs.xml** and there is:

```
<attr name="switchStyle" format="reference" />
```

Why I cant set a custom style for the switch widget despite the fact, that the attr is in **attrs.xml**?

And much more important: What do I have to do, to set a custom style for the Switch widget app wide?

Comment: Did you found a solution. I have the same problem. My themes.xml and styles.xml (values-v14) :
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:switchStyle">@style/SwitchAppTheme</item>
  </style>
    
 <style name="SwitchAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.Switch">
      <item name="android:track">@drawable/switch_track_holo_light</item>
      <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/switch_inner_holo_light</item>
  </style>

Comment: I have created an issue http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36636&thanks=36636&ts=1345753123

Answer (score 0):

try dropping "android:" in @style/CustomSwitch0. 
I believe you can only use the android namespace only if you are able to find it in here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html

Comment: switchStyle is only defined in Theme.Holo after android OS 3.0. make sure you inheret from Theme.Holo and compile it with the right target version.

Comment: Target is 14 (4.0). After your comment I although tried 15. No change.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36636), it looks like it isn't possible to inherit.

However, as a workaround, you could override the existing style (if it's just colors that you're dealing with) by creating the appropriate 9-patches etc at http://android-holo-colors.com/