# Switch Preference Compat not animating (Support Preference v7)

Tags: android

**Background:**
I am using SwitchPreferenceCompat of the support preference v7 library by extending it as below in order to have more than one line for the Switch title:

```
public class MoreLinesSwitchPreference extends SwitchPreferenceCompat {
    public MoreLinesSwitchPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MoreLinesSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MoreLinesSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder);

        TextView textView = (TextView) holder.itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        if (textView != null) {
            textView.setSingleLine(false);
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
        }
    }
}
```

My Preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:title="Settings">

    <com.sed.al_mabadi_ul_mufeedah.MyCustomListPreference
        android:defaultValue="20"
        android:entries="@array/fontSize"
        android:entryValues="@array/fontSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_format_size_24dp"
        android:key="fontSize"
        android:summary="20"
        android:title="@string/settings_font_size" />

    <com.sed.al_mabadi_ul_mufeedah.MyCustomListPreference
        android:defaultValue="DroidNaskh-Regular"
        android:entries="@array/font_face"
        android:entryValues="@array/font_face"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_font_24dp"
        android:key="fontFace"
        android:summary="Choose Font Name"
        android:title="@string/settings_font_name" />

    <com.sed.al_mabadi_ul_mufeedah.MyCustomListPreference
        android:defaultValue="en"
        android:entries="@array/language"
        android:entryValues="@array/language_short"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_language_24dp"
        android:key="language"
        android:summary="@string/app_restart"
        android:title="@string/app_language_title" />

    <com.sed.al_mabadi_ul_mufeedah.MoreLinesSwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_harakath_8b64ce_24dp"
        android:key="diacriticsOn"
        android:summary="@string/app_restart"
        android:title="@string/show_hide_diacritics" />

    <com.sed.al_mabadi_ul_mufeedah.MoreLinesSwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_night_24dp"
        android:key="nightModeOn"
        android:summary="@string/app_restart"
        android:title="@string/settings_night_mode" />

    <com.sed.al_mabadi_ul_mufeedah.MoreLinesSwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_screen_on"
        android:key="alwaysOn"
        android:summary="@string/sleep_on"
        android:title="@string/settings_screen_on" />

</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

from my Compile dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.2.0'
```

**MyStyle.xml:**

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorCursor</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorFocus</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryText</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorSecondaryText</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
</style>
```

**Problem:**

The SwitchPreferenceCompat is not animating between ON and OFF values.

**I researched:**

[Why SwitchPreference is not showing animation when switching from on to off & vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887962/why-switchpreference-is-not-showing-animation-when-switching-from-on-to-off-vi)

[Extending Preference classes in Android Lollipop = losing animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336635/extending-preference-classes-in-android-lollipop-losing-animation)

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185323

**Why the above does not answer my question:**

The above and other posts related to SwitchPreference does not speak about **SwitchPreferenceCompat** rather simply Switch or SwitchPreference

Need help in animating the switch between ON and OFF values.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet, I haven't found a solution. I am waiting for it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed now.
I updated the compile dependencies from

```
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.2.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.3.0'
```

and now the same switch preference is animating.
This could probably be a bug in the older versions of support preference.

Comment: If people are wondering for androidx Here is it:     `implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'`