# CheckBoxPreference SwitchCompat missing animation

Tags: android, android-animation, checkboxpreference, switchcompat

I have spent more than 10 hours trying to get the animation of the switch to work.

I have tried so many things that I don't remember several of the attempts, but I'll explain those that I remember.

**Code that should work (I think):**

I use the widgetLayout parameter:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:key="asd"
    android:title="@string/asd"
    android:widgetLayout="@layout/switchcompat_for_settings">
```

switchcompat_for_settings:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

No animation.

**Extending SwitchCompat with this code (best attempt??):**
https://gist.github.com/antifriz/ad4412b72d50f63ec977

Going from false to true there *is* an animation, going from true to false there *is no* animation.

Non ideal behaviour (but acceptable, if it can't be prevented): if the value is true it plays animation when the activity is loaded.

**Extending with following code:**

[Extending Preference classes in Android Lollipop = losing animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336635/extending-preference-classes-in-android-lollipop-losing-animation)

No animation at all.

```
@Override
public boolean isShown() {
    return getVisibility() == VISIBLE;
}
```

**Using SwitchPreference:**

Before Lollipop it has the old view, so not ideal because I would need different xml for before Lollipop and after.
If I have only one SwitchPreference I still have no animation. With several consecutive SwitchPreferences I get an animation in all but one (I've also checked with a new project with the Settings template and same problem).

Also, I prefer no animation in any Preference than animation in all but one.

**Adding a second Switch:**

In *switchcompat_for_settings* I add a second SwitchCompat and set the one with *id=@android:id/checkbox* to invisible. I extend the CheckboxPreference to override onBindView, and after calling `super.onBindView` I find the extra SwitchCompat and call `setChecked` to the appropriate value.

In the *onPreferenceClick* I call the setChecked of my extra switch.

It toggles without animation. My understanding is that the problem is that as onBindView is called A LOT of times (when creating the preference, and also each time I toggle it), it cancels the animation.

I tried to add a boolean to call setChecked in onBindView only after being called from onClick but did not succeed. Maybe it is the way to go and I did something wrong.

**Only remaining idea (not willing to do this):**
Add the switch manually to the activity root view, place in the correct position and handle from each activity that has this preference (several).